# Errors when trying to create ViewCell for multiple sqlite data for ListView in xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a ViewCell that looks like the one in the image render below. The pieces of data that should be in the ListView are stored in an sqlite database. But I keep getting an error that says "the name does not exist in the current context and I have no idea what to do.

My ListView code in XAML looks like this:

```xml
<ListView 
    x:Name="todayActivities"
    SeparatorColor="Transparent"
    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
    IsGroupingEnabled="true"
    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
    ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout 
                    Padding="10, 10, 10, 10">
                    <Label 
                        TextColor="White" 
                        FontSize="20" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                        x:Name="title"/>
                    <Grid>
                        <Label 
                            TextColor="White" 
                            FontSize="15" 
                            HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                            x:Name="location" 
                            Grid.Row="0" 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            Text="{Binding Activitylocation}"/>
                        <Label 
                            TextColor="White" 
                            FontSize="15" 
                            HorizontalOptions="End" 
                            x:Name="time" 
                            Grid.Row="0" 
                            Grid.Column="1"/>
                        <Label 
                            TextColor="White" 
                            FontSize="15" 
                            HorizontalOptions="End" 
                            x:Name="organizer" 
                            Grid.Row="1" 
                            Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <Button 
                            Text="Request to join" 
                            TextColor="White" 
                            FontSize="15" 
                            Clicked="Handle_Clicked_5" 
                            Grid.Row="1" 
                            Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackLayout>                                    
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Listview code in C# (Code-behind):

```cs
        DatabaseManager DBM = new DatabaseManager();

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        todayActivities.ItemsSource = DBM.GetTodayActivities();

        title.Text = DBM.GetTodayActivities().ToString();
        location.Text = DBM.GetTodayLocation().ToString();
        time.Text = DBM.GetTodayTimes().ToString();
        organizer.Text = DBM.GetTodayOrganizers().ToString();
```

//**This is where the errors show up ^ it says that the name "title/location/time..." does not exist in the current context**
        }

not sure if the Activites.cs code is relevant, but just in case it is:

```cs
public class Activities
{
    public string activityName { get; set; }
    public string activityDate { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string participants { get; set; }
    public string activityTime { get; set; }
    public string activityOrganizer { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return  activityName;
    }
}
```

DatabaseManager.cs:

```cs
public List<Activities> GetTodayActivities()
{
    return dbConnection.Query<Activities>("Select activityName, activityTime, location, activityOrganizer FROM [Activities]");
}
```

It should look like this in the end:
[image: expected result]

### UPDATE

Based on Jason's suggestion, I've made the following changes but getting an error that says "No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Children', or mismatching type between value and property." on line -1 for some reason.

XAML:

```xml
<Label 
    TextColor="White" 
    FontSize="20" 
    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
    x:Name="title" 
    Text="{Binding activityName}"/>

<Grid>
    <Label 
        TextColor="White" 
        FontSize="15" 
        HorizontalOptions="Start" 
        x:Name="location" 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.Column="0" 
        Text="{Binding location}"/>
    <Label 
        TextColor="White" 
        FontSize="15" 
        HorizontalOptions="End" 
        x:Name="time" 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.Column="1" 
        Text="{Binding activityTime}"/>
    <Label 
        TextColor="White" 
        FontSize="15" 
        HorizontalOptions="End" 
        x:Name="organizer" 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Grid.Column="0" 
        Text="{Binding activityOrganizer}"/>
    <Button 
        Text="Request to join" 
        TextColor="White" 
        FontSize="15" 
        Clicked="Handle_Clicked_5" 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

CodeBehind:

```cs
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    todayActivities.ItemsSource = DBM.GetTodayActivities();
}
```

As Tom requested, here is the full XAML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
                  x:Class="RoseySports.Home">




            <MasterDetailPage.Master>

        <ContentPage Title="Menu"> 
            <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
            Source="sidebar.jpg" Aspect="Fill"/>

        <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1">


        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Spacing="20">
        <Button Text="Create Activity" TextColor="White" Clicked="Handle_Clicked" FontSize="15"/>
            <Button Text="Check Availability" TextColor="White" FontSize="15" Clicked="Handle_Clicked_3"/>
            <Button Text="Check Invitations" TextColor="White" FontSize="15"/>
            <Button x:Name="SMA" Text="Propose Saturday Morning Activity" TextColor="White" FontSize="15"/>
            <Button x:Name="Logout" Text="Logout" Clicked="Handle_Clicked_1" TextColor="White" Margin="20" VerticalOptions="End" FontSize="20"/>            
        </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
            </ContentPage>
                </MasterDetailPage.Master>


            <MasterDetailPage.Detail>

            <ContentPage Title="Welcome To Le Rosey Sports">

        <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
            Source="background.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill"/>

        <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1">

                    <StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10, 40, 10, 10" Spacing="40">
                    <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="Start">

                                        <Button Image="menu.png" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="Start" Clicked="Handle_Clicked_2"/>

                                                                            </AbsoluteLayout>



                                                                            <Label Text="Today's Activities" FontSize="25" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>


                            </StackLayout>

                                            <ListView 
                            x:Name="todayActivities"
                            SeparatorColor="Transparent"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            IsGroupingEnabled="true"
                            IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                            ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>

                                    <ViewCell>

<StackLayout Padding="10, 10, 10, 10">

                                            <Label TextColor="White" FontSize="20" HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="title" Text="{Binding activityName}"/>

                                            <Grid>
                                            <Label TextColor="White" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="Start" x:Name="location" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding location}"/>
                                                <Label TextColor="White" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="End" x:Name="time" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding activityTime}"/>
                                            <Label TextColor="White" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="End" x:Name="organizer" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding activityOrganizer}"/>
                                            <Button Text="Request to join" TextColor="White" FontSize="15" Clicked="Handle_Clicked_5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>

                                             </Grid>


                                        </StackLayout>                                    
                                        </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>

                        </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>


        </ContentPage>

            </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Comment: please read the documentation on how to use a ListView.  You need to use databinding to populate the cell's values, you can't just assign values in the code behind.  Your DB queries are also wrong, they are only selecting a single column from the db, they should select all the properties needed to populate the Activities class

Comment: @Jason I've changed my DB query, but I've had issues with databinding to solve this issue. It got really confusing and didn't end up working, which is why I tried to simply assign the values in the code behind. But I'll give it another go and will update the question in case I need more help.

Comment: this doesn't work `Text="{Binding Activitylocation}"` because your class doesn't have an `Activitylocation` property.  It does have a `location` property, so if you use `"{Binding location}"` in the binding expression it should work.

Comment: I think you will need a where clause in your query if you want just today's activities.

Comment: @Mary yea I'm just trying to make it look like how I want it to before I put in a where clause to select just today's activities (have other issues with that).

Comment: @Jason I've done what you suggested, but I'm getting an error that says "No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Children', or mismatching type between value and property." I'll make an edit to the question showing what I've changed my code to.

Comment: it sounds like you have a typo or error elsewhere in your XAML

Comment: Couldn't find any typos, could there be another reason? The weird thing is that it says the error is in line -1

Comment: Here is a link for a tutorial on ListView and data binding. https://wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/

Comment: Looked over the tutorial, I think my data binding is fine, not sure what the issue is right now.

Comment: _No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Children', or mismatching type between value and property._ What's likely happened is that you've fixed the first issue you were having, and in turn has showed another error. Do a general search for "Children" and see where the error is actually occurring.

Comment: @Tom I did a general search for "Children" but nothing came up, and I couldn't find any issue with any other part of the app. I've never seen this error in the past and it only showed up after I solved the ListView issue. Which is why I think it specifically has to do with how I solved my ListView issue

Comment: @MohamedAlSabbagh Post the content of the file that the error is pointing to, and the full error message as well. There might be some code formatting issue.

Comment: Just posted the full content of the XAML file at the bottom of my question as that is where the error is pointing to, and the full error message is just like i said before, "No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Children', or mismatching type between value and property"

Comment: @MohamedAlSabbagh Have you done a Clean/Rebuild?

Comment: Yes I've tried it twice

Comment: the XAML you posted isn't valid - I assume it's just a snippet, not the "full content" that you claim

Comment: what do you mean by it isn't valid? This is the full content of the XAML code. Are you sure you're looking at the correct part of my post? The full XAML code is at the bottom of my post, not the beginning.